# How to design date grid UI like google flight search with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to design date grid UI like google flight search with Jetpack Compose?
I am unable to find any library or leads to achieve this using Jetpack compose.
[image]

Thank you!